# Doing calculations using javascript with select options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, select

Somebody please help me with some javascript coding. I am building a website using asp.net where there are multiple html select elements and their selected option determines what the value of an input box will be, see this link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evAuc

I am gonna have roughly 67 dropdown like this which would be a nightmare to code with an inefficient code.

Please help me write a more efficient code for these two selects and then I can do the rest by myself.

Cheers.

Comment: can you describe how the pertentages should be calculated? is it simply added?

Comment: i am thinking about how to explain this as it quite complex, give me some time plz

Comment: i am sorry it so complicated to explain in words - if you look at the js code, you can see how the calculation works exactly

Comment: @joelharkes I am going to try to explain, sorry if doesn't help
- basically both the dropdowns have a control variable
- depending on the selected option value
- the dropdowns assign value to two variable each by multiplication with the control variable
- the first values and second values for both dropdowns are add seperately into two sums
- then they are divided by each other
hope this explains something

Comment: ok, but in those 67 dropdowns, what is variable: is the only difference that there are 67 dropdowns or has every dropdown different values with different control variables? <- that would make the code more complex

Comment: unfortunately, all the dropdowns have different control variables and different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i split your code up in parts (i used jquery), though you should still change the function names and the calculateValue implementation to make your code more clear.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initCalculation($('#keyTechTextBox'),$("#dropdown_serverVirtualisation"),$("#dropdown_desktopVirtualisation"));
    //more can be added here
});

function initCalculation(inputField,select1,select2){
    select1.change(function(){ //this can be done more generic
       inputField.val(calculateValue(select1.val(),select2.val()).toFixed(0)+"%");
    });
    select2.change(function(){
        inputField.val(calculateValue(select1.val(),select2.val()).toFixed(0)+"%");
    });
}

function calculateValue(firstOpt,secondOpt){ //more abstract function name please :D
    //you should really optimize this.. - i did some
    var sV_Value = 10;
    var sV1 =0;
    var sV2 = sV_Value;
    var dV1 =0;
    var dV2 = dV_Value;
    if (firstOpt === "G") {
        sV1 = sV_Value;
    }
    if (firstOpt === "O") {
        sV1 = sV_Value * 0.5;
    }
    if (firstOpt === "A") {
        sV1 = sV_Value * 0.3;
    }
    if (firstOpt === "R") {
        sV1 = 0;
    } else if (firstOpt === "U") {
        sV1 = 0;
    }
    if (secondOpt === "N") {
        dV2 = 0;
    }
    if (secondOpt === "G") {
        dV1 = dV_Value;
    }
    if (secondOpt === "O") {
        dV1 = dV_Value * 0.5;
    }
    if (secondOpt === "A") {
        dV1 = dV_Value * 0.3;
    }
    var keyTechTotal1 = sV1 + dV1;
    var keyTechTotal2 = sV2 + dV2;
    return (keyTechTotal1) / (keyTechTotal2) * 100;
}
```

Below i show you a more generic javascript solution

change the min and max attributes for each option in html and from there start calculating.

You can genericly insert the data min and max attributes in .net

```
<input class="textBox" runat="server" type="text" id="keyTechTextBox" readonly="true" />
<select runat="server" id="dropdown_serverVirtualisation" onchange="keyTechAdoption()">
    <option class="lightgrey" value="N" data-min="0" data-max="1">N</option>
    <option class="green" value="G"  data-min="0" data-max="1">G</option>
    <option class="orange" value="O" data-min="0" data-max="1">O</option>
    <option class="yellow" value="A" data-min="0" data-max="1">A</option>
    <option selected="selected" class="red" value="R" data-min="0" data-max="1">R</option>
    <option class="purple" value="U" data-min="0" data-max="1">U</option>
</select>
<select runat="server" id="dropdown_desktopVirtualisation" onchange="keyTechAdoption()">
    <option class="lightgrey" value="N" data-min="0" data-max="1">N</option>
    <option class="green" value="G" data-min="0" data-max="1">G</option>
    <option class="orange" value="O" data-min="0" data-max="1">O</option>
    <option class="yellow" value="A" data-min="0" data-max="1">A</option>
    <option selected="selected" class="red" value="R" data-min="0" data-max="1">R</option>
    <option class="purple" value="U" data-min="0" data-max="1">U</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initCalculation(inputField,select1,select2){
        opt1 = select1.find('option:selected');
        opt2 = select2.find('option:selected');
        select1.change(function(){ //this can be done more generic
            inputField.val(calculateValue(opt1,opt2).toFixed(0)+"%");
        });
        select2.change(function(){
            inputField.val(calculateValue(opt1,opt2).toFixed(0)+"%");
        });
    }

    function calculateOptions(el1,el2){
        calculateValue(el1.data('min'),el1.data('max'),el1.data('min'),el1.data('max'));
    }

    function calculateValue(sV1,sV2,dV1,dV2){ //more abstract function name please :D
        var keyTechTotal1 = sV1 + dV1;
        var keyTechTotal2 = sV2 + dV2;
        return (keyTechTotal1) / (keyTechTotal2) * 100;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help - i will try to make it efficient as much as i can